# Use variables in build step configuration

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, sonarqube-scan

I am using the new agent build system with TFS 2015 and TFS "15" and have SonarQube tasks in my build to do source code analysis.
Now I would like to increase the version sent to SonarQube on every build. I tried the following to achive that:
[image]
But that does not work - the version is sent to SonarQube as it is there and not with the inserted build id.
**How can I pass an increasing version number to SonarQube?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try $(Build.BuildNumber)?
Any way, all the available build variables can be found [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/define/variables)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I already used that list, but I took the wrong names. I used the "environment variable name" instead of the "variable name" x-P...